# open with dialog box in android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have downloaded a file using download Manager option in my service. In the notification download manager shows the file is downloaded and when I click on it automatically according to fileType the app opens and I can read the file.

Now I would like do the same immediately after download is completed. (I don't have the file type - this is dynamic) So I was thinking of getting **"open with"** dialog box and then let the user choose.

Question is How do I trigger the **"Open with"** option?

Say for example: I have a PDF file. I don't know the file type so I would like to show "Open With" dialog box and user can choose the reader?

This is what I tried:

Under "case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:" in download manager code.

I tried the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This opens only file manager, what is the best way to show "Open With" option because I don;t have the fileType with this..

again I am running the download Manager part in service.

Thanks!

Comment: Android only presents an Open With dialog when it find more than one app that can satisfy the request.  If there is only one, it will go ahead and use it.  You can build one yourself, however, but that will take a lot of coding on your part.

Comment: @DougStevenson: I understand that but my question is not that I would like to show Open With Dialog box. Say for e.g for I have PDF download I don't know if this is PDF file in general I want to open with option and user can decide to open the file.

Comment: I don't think you can do that because the mime type of the item to open must be known, becaues that will be used to determine which apps are capable of opening it.

Comment: @DougStevenson: what happens with there is no app that can open the the file type.

Comment: @SanjanaNair see this link hope this will help you ..http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/